# how to improve efficiency in determine whether a tree is an AVL tree in python?

Tags: python, recursion, avl-tree

Currently there are two recursive layers in my following code. I was wondering is it possible to "merge" the two in the sense that code is more efficient?

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return 0
        return max(self.maxDepth(root.left), self.maxDepth(root.right))+1

    def isBalanced(self, root):

        if root == None:
            return True
        if abs(self.maxDepth(root.left) - self.maxDepth(root.right)) <= 1:
            return self.isBalanced(root.left) and self.isBalanced(root.right)
        return False
```

Comment: Merging code doesn't imply that it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

To define a function that checks if a tree is perfectly balanced or not, you can visit only once the tree with an algorithm given in the following pseudo-code (I do not know enough the Python syntax to write an explicit code):

```
isBalanced(tree):
  if tree is null 
  then return the tuple (true, 0)
  else be (bal1, lev1) the result of calling isBalanced on the left child of tree
   and be (bal2, lev2) the result of calling isBalanced on the rigth child of tree
     if (bal1 is false) or (bal2 is false)
     then exit from the function with the tuple (false, 0)
     else if lev1 = lev2
          then return the tuple (true, 1+lev1)
          else exit from the function with the tuple (false, 0)
```

Basically the algorithm visits the tree calculating recursively if a subtree is balanced or not, and, *in case it is balanced*, the depth of the tree.

The command “exit from the function” should cause the immediate exit from all the recursive calls of the function, if this is possible in Python, otherwise it is simply a return from the current call with the tuple specified.

Of course, at the end of the function, only the first component of the tuple (the information about the balancedness), is useful.

If you want to check if a tree is balanced with at most a difference of 1 on the depth of the leaves, you could extend this solution by returning a tuple with three elements (balanced, minimun depth, maximum depth), and checking in the general case if the depths (minimum and maximum) of the children are consistent (and then return the current minimum and maximum).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Python translation of [Renzo's pseudocode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34397952/):

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def isBalanced(tree):
    exitValue = None

    def isBalancedCore(tree):
        nonlocal exitValue
        if exitValue is not None:
            return exitValue

        if tree is None:
            return (True, 0)
        else:
            bal1, lev1 = isBalancedCore(tree.left)
            bal2, lev2 = isBalancedCore(tree.right)
            if not bal1 or not bal2:
                exitValue = (False, 0)
                return exitValue
            elif lev1 == lev2:
                return (True, lev1+1)
            else:
                exitValue = (False, 0)
                return exitValue

    return isBalancedCore(tree)[0]
```